# how to dynamically determine the view model using Catel Mvvm

Tags: catel

Catel MVVM framework is a very good mvvm framework, It automaticaly maps views to viewmodels, saving a lot time of my daily work. 
Now I encountered a problem, I want to map one view to a few of veiw models during runtime, i searched catel offical document, and found it said:

"
Determining the view model dynamically when using the UserControl is     extremely easy. You can override the GetViewModelType(object) method like this:

```
protected override Type GetViewModelType(object dataContext)
{
    if (dataContext is Rectangle)
    {
        return typeof (RectangleViewModel);
    }

    if (dataContext is Circle)
    {
        return typeof (CircleViewModel);
    }

    return null;
}
```

"

but dont't know where to override above GetViewModelType, I even did not find this method in Catel source codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GetViewModelType is obsolete. If you found it in the docs, please let me know where, then I will remove it (or feel free to remote it yourself, it's all editable for everyone).

You can register a custom view model mapping like this in the startup of your app:

```
var dependencyResolver = this.GetDependencyResolver();
var viewModelLocator = dependencyResolver.Resolve<IViewModelLocator>();

viewModelLocator.RegisterView<MyDrawingView, RectangleViewModel>();
```

If you want it more dynamic, you can implement your own `IViewModelFactory` where you can return the right view model based on the model being passed in.

Comment: Is there a way that i can create three same view instances and map each to different view model instance (shape view <-> rectangle vm, shape view <-> circle vm, shape view <-> square) in the same time?  otherwise I have to create one view and one view model and 3 different models. Thank you! :)

Comment: That's not going to be easy I'm afraid. The only other thing you could do is use DataTemplates or a converter to convert a model to a view model yourself. Catel will use ViewModels set as DataContext.